# Distributing iOS frameworks with restricted access

Tags: ios, maven, frameworks, software-distribution

I need to do controlled distribution (using username & password) of an iOS framework that I'm working on. I can't publicly host the framework due to some regulatory concerns. So, Cocoapods as a solution doesn't work for me.

I have looked at Android's maven integration and it seems to work smoothly. Where a user has to enter a username and password to be able to download binaries.

Does a similar solution exist in iOS landscape?